# Openlayers: Making the map move with moving vector layer (airplane) on map

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

So currently I have a map that has some plane data. There is a `setInterval` function that updates the plane data every 5 seconds, making the plane move from point to point. That is working well.

```
function planeInterval() {
    setInterval(function() {planeMovement()}, 5000);
    //this is currently working
}

function planeMovement() {
    //do some stuff to make the plane move around
    //this is currently working

}
```

Now, I would like to set up a checkbox or some sort of toggle to:

**-toggle on: as the plane moves across the map, the map MOVES as the plane moves**

**-toggle off: the plane just does what it usually does: moves across the map while the map stays stagnant.**

I was looking into OL `panTo` but I don't think that's the answer here. What would be the best/most simple approach in achieving this?

Comment: Official Animated example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/filter-strategy.html

Comment: So this is the route to take to get the MAP to move? Even though I already have the plane moving on the map (like the example is doing)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the center of the map to the airplane position after it has refreshed.

OpenLayers [setCenter](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setCenter)

Comment: Right right, of course I made it more complicated/overthought it. Thanks for the reply, it worked.